# Installer VSIX error (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I was trying to update "Github Extension for Visual Studio"

I opened "Extension and Updates", clicked to update the extension — it is downloaded and VS showed message:

> Your changes will be sheduled. The modification will begin when all
>   Visual Studio windows are closed.

Then I closed VS and error happened.

> Installer VSIX
>   Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the  following
>   error: 80040154. Class not registered (exception from
>   hresult: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

The extension was not updated.

The same thing happens when I try to install a new VS Extension.
I was trying to start VS as Administrator.

Windows 10, VS2017

Comment: Try running a repair of Visual Studio (Add or Remove Programs -> VS2017 -> Context Menu -> Repair).

Comment: Google like guids, just google them and you'll find the answer at developercommunity.visualstudio.com/

Comment: I was not trying to repair, because I was reinstalling VS recently. But It works! (Visual Studio Installer / Repair)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Visual Studio before this question, so didn't try `Repair` option, but
`Visual Studio Installer → Repair` helps.